# reload/refresh data in TableAdapter without fill again

Tags: c#

I have 2 forms, in one of them I show DataTable rows in a combo box.
and in second form, I will edit that rows.
How can i reload that changes that are made by second form, in first form?
I don't wanna use TablaAdpater.Fill for reload!
thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

Re-bind your DataTable with your combobox.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same data table
then try to refresh the data source of your combo box. else rebind.

Comment: How can I refresh my data source?

Comment: then u have to rebind the combo with data table.. Or you can use 
ObservableCollection<T> as your data source. In this case you don't have to worry this sort of thing.